# How does articles_path work? (RubyOnRails tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I am following [the official ruby on rails tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and I just finished chapter 5.9.

Adding links should be simple but I am majorly confused.

When I type `bin/rake routes`, I get the following output:

```
fl4m3ph03n1x: ~/blog $ bin/rake routes
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
        root GET    /                            welcome#index
fl4m3ph03n1x: ~/blog $
```

Which makes sense according to the tutorial.

To make use of this, I have a view:

```
<h1>New Article</h1>

<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

This view has a submit form and a link in the end. 
According to ruby, I specify the submit button link in the form by using `articles_path` in `<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>`.

I really have no idea how that variable is set, but I will take the bait and accept it. 
According to the tutorial, when clicking the submit button `articles_path` will be "POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create" by default.

However, in the link `<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>`, `articles_path` is supposed to redirect us to the index page...

Can someone explain me how the same variable has 2 radically different behaviors in the same View ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **How action view methods work :**

**`link_to`** default request type is 'GET'.

**`button_to`** default request type is 'POST'.

Each generated route has a specific type, which is how rails map different requests to the correct ones.

For `form_for` action view helper method, it differentiates between 'POST' and 'PUT' automatically depending on whether you passed an instance or not to the form.

you can also explicitly provide the method type for the form by adding

```
method: 'GET' OR :html => { :method => 'GET' }
```

** check different syntax capabilities depending on rails version.

Same goes to other methods, so if you want `link_to` to send post request you have to pass `method="POST"` to it.

---

### **How rails differentiate between index and show  actions **

In the generated routes table you may have noticed that index action does NOT need an instance id because it is supposed to list all articles. However, for show, you need to pass an instance to it, because it is supposed to show a specific instance only.

```
= link_to "index", articles_path
= link_to "show", article_path(article)
```

**NOTICE ::**

The two methods is not the same, "articles" and "article", plural vs singular. Even if they were identical in names one of them will take an instance and the other won't.

Comment: How do I know if the GET request I am sending is for index, show,new or edit?

Comment: I updated my answer check the second section. Try to read the generated routes, this would give you more insights and explanations.

Comment: "The two methods is not the same, "articles" and "article", plural vs singular."  This helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The better you can understand when you look into the ***HTML*** output it generates.

`<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>` generates the ***HTML*** output something like below

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/articles/create" method="post">
```

So the ***form*** submits to the ***create action*** with a ***POST*** request.

When it comes to `link_to`, the default request type is ***GET***.

The ***HTML*** output generated for `<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>` will be something like below

```
<a href="/artcles">Back</a>
```

so the it takes you to the ***index page*** as it matches the ***url*** and ***request type***.

Answer (score 0):

There is bit magic behind, form builder know that method http method will be POST and url will be /articles. Same as when you will be developing edit action then form builder will know that action will PATH/PUT and url will be /articles/1 because you will have to pass instance of article to form helper.

Same magic is link_to helper he knows that default is GET http method unless you exactly specify.